# \input{} as argument for \inputgraphic{}

Tags: macros, expansion, input, shell-escape

I got a question very similar to this post ([\includegraphics{\input{|shell command}}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150584/includegraphics-inputshell-command)) which unfortunately hasn't been really answered.

The aim is to make a command that invokes a python script to make a plot figure, which is then inserted in LaTeX. What I have tried so far is the following:

*main.tex:*

```
\newcommand\pytexplot[1]{
   \immediate\write18{python pytexplot.py #1}
   \input{shellout}
}

\begin{document}

\includegraphic{\pytexplot{plot1}}
\includegraphic{\pytexplot{plot2}}

\end{document}
```

pytexplot.py is a python script that makes different plots depending on the provided parameter and saves a file shellout.tex containing the name and location of the image of the generated plot.

The error thus reported is an undefined control sequence (100+ in total), so I'm afraid this won't help much..

So far I figured it has to do with macro expansions, and tried putting in `\expandafter` at different positions but to no avail.

EDIT: wipet's 2nd suggestion seems to work, but it includes the same plot twice. Also, I don't know how to combine it with the shell command

Could someone help me out on this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: I think you just want `input{shellout}` assuming `shellout.tex` is the file congaing the desired plot.  If that does not answer your question I'd suggest you compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem.

Comment: Side note: there is no `\includegraphic`, it is `\includegraphics`. A `MWE` starting with `\documentclass` would be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the file `shellout.tex` just contains one line with the file name of the generated file, then

```
\usepackage{catchfile}
\newcommand{\includeplot}[2][]{%
  \immediate\write18{python pytexplot.py #2}%
  \CatchFileDef\plotpath{shellout.tex}{\endlinechar=-1 }%
  \includegraphics[#1]{\plotpath}%
}
```

in the preamble, with

```
\includeplot{plot1}
```

in the document or

```
\includeplot[<options for \includegraphics>]{plot1}
```

should do what you need.

Comment: Thanks, this actually works for me! On top of that, I now define the folders in LaTeX and pass them as arguments to python, eliminating the need for python to pass its output to LaTeX again.

Answer (score 4):

When you've got a shell command which creates `plot1` in `shellout.tex` file, then you can simply modify this shell command in order it creates

```
\includegraphics{plot1}
```

instead simple `plot1` in the `shelloupt.tex` file. And you can simply use

```
\input shellout
```

But if you insist on the idea that your shell command creates only `plot1` in your `shellout.tex` file then the code is slightly more complicated:

```
{\everyeof={\noexpand}\xdef\filecontent{\csname @@input\endcsname shellout }}
\def\tmp#1 {\def\filecontent{#1}}\expandafter\tmp\filecontent
\expandafter\includegraphics\expandafter{\filecontent}
```

**Edit:** The question were edited, the reaction to this modification follows.

You can define

```
\def\pytexplot#1{%
   \immediate\write18{python pytexplot.py #1}%
   {\endlinechar=-1\everyeof={\noexpand}\xdef\filecontent{\csname @@input\endcsname shellout }}%
   \includegraphics\filecontents
}
```

and you can use only

```
\pytexplot{plot1}
\pytexplot{plot2}
```

If you explicitly needs to write `\includegraphics{\pytexplot{...}}` in your document then you have to redefine `\includegraphics` like `\pytexplot` above and `\def\pytexplot#1{#1}`. But if you are using the command `\includegraphics` to another needs then this is not so simple. You need to implement more intelligence to your `\includegraphics` redefinition.

Comments:

1. The `\tmp` in my first code removes the space generated by `\endlinechar`. But setting `\endlinechar=-1` locally (suggested by jfbu) seems to be better, so I use this in my second code.
2. IMHO simplest solution is to generate the `\includegraphics{out1}`, `\includegraphics{out2}` by python and to define:
   `\def\pytexplot#1{\immediate\write18{python pytexplot.py #1}\input shellout }`

Comment: It seems to do what I requested alright, but it's still not working out completely for me. I will update the original question with a full MWE. In the mean time, could you perhaps explain what's going on step by step? I'm not sure how the \tmp command comes into play..

Comment: @wipet  with `\endlinechar-1\relax` perhaps you would not need the `\tmp` thing.

Comment: I believe that `\CatchFileDef\filecontent{shellout}{\endlinechar=-1 }` will avoid many headaches (requires `\usepackage{catchfile}`).

Comment: The reason I don't want python to output the \includegraphics line is that I have a lot of plots, and I want to be able to control each of the included graphics by parameters in LaTeX. I think what would work for me is make a new macro, say, \includepytexplot that can take all the arguments that \includegraphics has.

Answer (score 1):

[moved from a comment]

Just to provide additional context to already given answers:

You can not, in general, hope to pass to some LaTeX command expecting something like a filename, a macro as argument; at best (and not always) the command will be of the type which attempts to expand its argument, and as soon as this argument does *unexpandable* things, it is highly probable that the command will not function.

In the case of `\includegraphics` you can use it with `\temp` as argument if `\temp` expands to a legitimate file name. But if `\temp` needs to make definitions, or contains a `\write` operation, you are doomed (no matter how many `\expandafter` you try to fiddle with)