Use a File as Input for a Macro with the `listofitems` Package
After a saga about parsing SGF files that culminated in this very thorough answer by user @StevenB.Segletes, I've been trying to use files as input for the macro he was able to create there. The final command looks like this for me now — the rest of the code you can just simply copy-paste from the main code block of that answer, which is an MWE, but I'll also copy it down below —:
\parseSgf{\input{1.sgf}}

The errors I'm getting seem to be about nullfonts, which may be something specific to TikZ? I'm getting one of these for each character in the file:
There is no ( in font nullfont!

In general, for an arbitrary macro, using \input{...} in this way seems to work, I don't know why it doesn't here. For example, doing something like this did work for me:
\documentclass{book}

\newcommand{\test}[1]{
  \Large #1
}

\begin{document}
  \test{\input{1.sgf}}
\end{document}

Just for reference, here's a copy of the main code block from @StevenB.Segletes' answer:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{listofitems}

%-----------------------------------------------------------
% Drawing Stones

% From [this answer by @DavidCarlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/708876/64441).
\newcommand\notwhite{black}
\newcommand\notblack{white}

% From [this answer by @DavidCarlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/708893/64441).
\ExplSyntaxOn
  \cs_generate_variant:Nn \int_from_alph:n {e}

  \NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\stringToCoordX}{ m }{
    \int_from_alph:e { \use_i:nn #1 }
  }
  \NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\stringToCoordY}{ m }{
    \boardSize + 1 - ~\int_from_alph:e { \use_ii:nn #1 }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\setCoords}[1]{
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{\stringToCoordX{#1} - 1}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{\stringToCoordY{#1} - 1}
}

\newcommand{\drawStoneFromSgfCoords}[2]{%
  \setCoords{#2}

  \draw[draw = \UseName{not#1}, fill = #1, line width = 0.1mm]
    (\x * \step, \y * \step)
    circle [radius = 0.2575cm];
}

\newcommand{\drawMoveFromSgfCoords}[2]{
  \expandafter\xdef\csname thecolorat#2\endcsname{#1}% SAVE COLOR AT #2
  \drawStoneFromSgfCoords{#1}{#2}
  \textLabel{#1}{#2}{\themoveCounter}

  \stepMoveCounter
}

\newcounter{moveCounter}
\setcounter{moveCounter}{1}

\newcommand{\stepMoveCounter}{
  \stepcounter{moveCounter}
}

%-----------------------------------------------------------
% Labels

\newcommand\StoneColor[1]{% COMPLEMENTARY COLOR OF REFERENCED STONE
  \ifcsname thecolorat#1\endcsname
    \csname thecolorat#1\endcsname
  \else
    white% COMPLEMENT OF DEFAULT LABEL COLOR WHEN NOT ATOP EXISTING STONE
  \fi
}

\newcommand{\textLabel}[3]{%
  \setCoords{#2}%
  \draw (\x * \step, \y * \step) 
  node[
    color = -\StoneColor{#2},
    fill = \StoneColor{#2},
    inner sep=1pt
  ] {#3};
}

\newcommand{\crossLabel}[2]{
  \setCoords{#2}
  \draw (\x * \step, \y * \step) 
  node[
    color = -\StoneColor{#2},
    fill = \StoneColor{#2},
    inner sep=1pt
  ] {$\times$};
}

\newcommand{\triangleLabel}[2]{
  \setCoords{#2}
  \draw (\x * \step, \y * \step) 
    node[
      isosceles triangle,
      draw                          = #1,
      line width                    = 0.5mm,
      color                         = -\StoneColor{#2},
      fill                          = -\StoneColor{#2},
      minimum height                = \step * 10,
      minimum width                 = \step * 10,
      rotate                        = 90,
      isosceles triangle apex angle = 60,
      inner sep                     = 0pt,
    ] {};
}

\newcommand{\squareLabel}[2]{
  \setCoords{#2}

  \draw (\x * \step, \y * \step) 
    node[
      draw         = #1,
      line width   = 0.5mm,
      color        = -\StoneColor{#2},
      fill         = -\StoneColor{#2},
      minimum size = \step * 10,
      inner sep    = 0pt,
    ] {};
}

\newcommand{\circleLabel}[2]{
  \setCoords{#2}

  \draw[
    draw         = #1,
    line width   = 0.5mm,
    color        = -\StoneColor{#2},
    fill         = -\StoneColor{#2},
    inner sep    = 0pt,
  ] (\x * \step, \y * \step) 
    circle[radius = \step / 4];
}

%-----------------------------------------------------------
% SGF Parser

% From [this answer by @StevenB.Segletes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/709014/64441).
\long\def\Firstof#1#2\endFirstof{#1}

\newcommand\thecolorofB{black}
\newcommand\thecolorofAB{black}
\newcommand\thecolorofW{white}
\newcommand\thecolorofAW{white}
\newcommand\thecolorofMA{white}
\newcommand\thecolorofCR{white}
\newcommand\thecolorofTR{white}
\newcommand\thecolorofSQ{white}
\newcommand\thecolorofLB{white}

\long\def\Keytypeof#1{\csname thekeytypeof#1\endcsname}

\newcommand\thekeytypeofB{M}  % black move
\newcommand\thekeytypeofAB{A} % added (edited) black stone
\newcommand\thekeytypeofW{M}  % white move
\newcommand\thekeytypeofAW{A} % added (edited) white stone
\newcommand\thekeytypeofMA{K} % cross (mark) label
\newcommand\thekeytypeofCR{C} % circle label
\newcommand\thekeytypeofTR{T} % triangle label
\newcommand\thekeytypeofSQ{S} % square label
\newcommand\thekeytypeofLB{L} % text label

\newcommand{\parseSgf}[1]{%
  \setsepchar{(||)/;/]/[/:}%
  \readlist*\Z{#1}%

  \foreachitem \Branch \in \Z[]{%
  \foreachitem \Group \in \Z[\Branchcnt]{%
    \foreachitem \Key \in \Z[\Branchcnt, \Groupcnt]{%
     \if\relax\Key\relax% IF BLANK KEY & VALUE, SKIP
     \else
      \itemtomacro\Z[\Branchcnt, \Groupcnt, \Keycnt, 1]\KeyName
      \if\relax\KeyName\relax% IF VALUE, BUT NO KEYNAME, USE RECENT KEYNAME
        \let\KeyName\MostRecentKeyname
      \else
        \xdef\MostRecentKeyname{\KeyName}%
      \fi
      \itemtomacro\Z[\Branchcnt, \Groupcnt, \Keycnt, 2, 1]\KeyValue

      \edef\tmp{{\csname thecolorof\KeyName\endcsname}{\KeyValue}}%

      \if\Keytypeof\KeyName M
        \expandafter\drawMoveFromSgfCoords\tmp
      \fi
      \if\Keytypeof\KeyName A
        \expandafter\drawStoneFromSgfCoords\tmp
      \fi
      \if\Keytypeof\KeyName K
        \expandafter\crossLabel\tmp
      \fi
      \if\Keytypeof\KeyName C
        \expandafter\circleLabel\tmp
      \fi
      \if\Keytypeof\KeyName T
        \expandafter\triangleLabel\tmp
      \fi
      \if\Keytypeof\KeyName S
        \expandafter\squareLabel\tmp
      \fi
      \if\Keytypeof\KeyName L
        \expandafter\textLabel\tmp{\Z[\Branchcnt, \Groupcnt, \Keycnt, 2, 2]} 
      \fi
     \fi
    }
  }%
  }%
}

%-----------------------------------------------------------
% SGFs

\def\sgfE{(
  ;GM[1]FF[4]CA[UTF-8]AP[CGoban:3]ST[2]RU[Japanese]SZ[19]KM[6.50]DT[2023-12-25]
  ;B[pd]
  ;W[dd]
  ;B[dp]
  ;W[pp]
  ;AW[ji][jn][kn][ln]AB[jj][jm][km]TR[jp][kp][lp]PL[B]
  ;B[jq]CR[pp]LB[dd:A][jd:C][pd:B]TR[jj]SQ[ji]MA[dp]
)}

%-----------------------------------------------------------
% Setup

\pgfmathsetmacro{\boardDimension}{10}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\boardSize}{19}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\step}{\boardDimension / (\boardSize - 1)}

%-----------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[step=\step] (0, 0) grid (10, 10);

    \parseSgf{\sgfE}
    
    \textLabel{white}{ab}{A}
    \triangleLabel{black}{ac}
    \squareLabel{black}{ad}
    \circleLabel{black}{ae}
    \crossLabel{white}{af}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


To apply the duplicate to your question you can for example define a new command \newcommand\parseSgfFile[1]{% \CatchFileDef{\mysgf}{#1}{}% \parseSgf{\mysgf}% } (with a new line after each %, which cannot be shown in a comment on the site here), and then inside of the tikzpicture put `\draw[step=\step] (0, 0) grid (10, 10);
\parseSgfFile{1.sgf} etc.`.


That doesn't answer why reading the file into the macro example I created worked, while with the longer one it didn't.

As for why it sometimes works and not here: it only works if the substitution inside a command is valid. \Large \input{something.txt} could be used normally, it first sets the \Large font for all following text and then it inputs the text. Here however it would come down to \readlist*\Z{\input{something}}, which is not the kind of argument that \readlist understands.

I think it would be much more useful to use your comments to create a normal answer, rather than labeling this as a duplicate. I'll try to create an answer soon, if all that works.

You could write an answer, however you basically ask two different questions (why doesn't this work, and how can I get it to work), the second is a duplicate of the (more general) question that I linked, the first is most likely also a duplicate but of a different question - I will try to find a duplicate for that as well if I have time.

For example https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/203553/ is quite related (but there are probably better duplicate candidates to be found).

I've just tested your comments, and it works! Thank you very much! I've added an answer of mine below based on it. But, of course, I don't intend on stealing your efforts. So, if you would like to create your own, I'll grant it the points and answer instead of my own.

As per @Marjin's very useful comments, from this answer, we can simply add this and it works:
\usepackage{catchfile}

\newcommand\parseSgfFile[1]{%
  \CatchFileDef{\mysgf}{#1}{}%
  \parseSgf{\mysgf}% 
}

Now, instead of using \parseSgf{...}, we can use this with the filename \parseSgfFile{1.sgf}.
